# Ionic 2 build android fails (Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater)

Tags: java, android, ionic2

I'm trying to run `ionic cordova build android` on Ubuntu and get the following error:

```
    You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
    ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
    Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

As you can see, JAVA_HOME is pointing to JDK 8.

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Here's the output of `ionic info`

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
    Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 2.0.2
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
    Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.3

System:

    Node       : v8.2.1
    OS         : Linux 4.4
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 5.3.0
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

After installing oracle jdk, I'm still getting the same error.

```
    You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
    ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-oracle
    Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-oracle

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/usr/bin/javac was pointing to jdk 7. Changed it to point to the *OpenJDK* version 8 with the command `sudo update-alternatives --config javac` and all is good. I am now able to build it - even with the OpenJDK 8 java so no need to install oracle jdk.